# how should I declare .map in react?

Tags: reactjs

I want to render Todo in my Todolist. but in (todos.map ) portion not working.

```js
import React from "react";
import Todo from './Todo';
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const TodoList=( {todos})=>{
    
    return (
        <div class="todo-container">
<ul class="todo-list">
    {todos.map(todo=>(
        <Todo />
    ))}
</ul>
        </div>
    );

};
export default TodoList
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `key` property. A unique identifier per item

https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Edit: Something like this

```
<ul class="todo-list">
  {todos.map(todo=>(
    <Todo key={todo.id} />
  ))}
</ul>
```

where `todo.id` is some unique identifier.

Comment: how should i declare it ?

Comment: as a property. edit in answer